# Given generator $g$ with prime order $k$ in $\bmod P$. Does increasing $P = 2 \cdot c \cdot k +1$ decrease security? Increasing $g$ increase security?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, attack

An adversary wants to find $a$ in

$$m \equiv  g^a \bmod P$$

He knows prime $P = 2 \cdot c \cdot k +1$ with it's primes $c,k$, value $m$ and $g$. And he also knows that $g$ only has an order of $k$, so:
$$g^k \equiv 1  \bmod P$$

---

**Question:**
If now the prime value $P$ gets increased for constant $k$ (order of $g$ still $k$ only factor $c$ gets increased) does this decrease the security?

Why this? If $P \rightarrow \infty $ it would be the normal logarithm which is easy to compute compared to discrete version.

The smaller the better (for same $k$)? Any boundary for best security?

---

Discrete Log is hard because it is always reduced to a number from $0$ to $P-1$.
 Is security bound to the number of multiplications of generator $g$ needed until over $P$ again? The less the better?

**Question part 2**:
Would be a higher value for $g$ increase security? (best would be $(P-1)/2$?)
Or to be more certain would a higher smallest group element $\not=1$ increase security?

Comment: @kelalaka This algorithm reduces the problem to the largest prime factor of the order size. But that is already the case. $g$ has order $k$ which is a prime factor of $P-1$. So you saying the security is independent of $P$ with constant order size $k$?

Comment: @kelalaka $k$ has fixed size and is prime, so just factor $c$ gets increased.

Comment: @kelalaka all should be primes $k,c,P$. So only selected primes values for $c$ are possible which result in a prime $P$ as well and $P=2ck+1$ is still true for the same $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If now the prime value $P$ gets increased for constant $k$ (order of $g$ still $k$) does this decrease the security?

No, for random choice of $g$ among $g$ with large constant order $k$.

> Why this? If $P \rightarrow \infty$ it would be the normal logarithm ..

When $P$ grows, $g$ also grows. So we never reach the threshold where $g^a<P$. Thus we can not use the normal logarithm.

> The smaller the better (for same $k$)?

Uh, no, on the contrary! The above says that larger $P$ does not decrease security. Correspondingly, larger $P$ tends to increase security. However, very large $P$ does not *much* increase security, because the best known algorithms we have for the discrete logarithm for fixed $k$ and large $P$ perform a number of modular multiplications modulo $P$ that is a function¹ of $k$ only, and the time necessary for a multiplication modulo $P$ grows relatively slowly with $P$: in the order of $O(\log^2 P)$ for the simplest and common methods².

> Any boundary for best security?

Only a lower boundary, and that's a nontrivial subject. The short answer might be: at least $2^{4095}$ (that is $P$ of $2^{12}$ bits) with $P$ not chosen close to the power of an integer.

The long answer includes that security against classical computers (not hypothetical quantum computers usable for cryptanalysis per e.g. [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm)) is believed to be limited by several possible attacks:

- the Number Field Sieve, which efficiency is governed mostly by $P$, and which general form the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (the only form likely to be applicable to $P$ not chosen close to the power of an integer, a situation where [the Special Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_number_field_sieve) shines) is believed to require a $P$ in the order of at least $2^{11}$ to $2^{13}$ bits for security.
- [Pollard's rho](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/), which efficiency is governed mostly by $k$, requiring a $k$ in the order of at least $2^8$ to $2^9$ bits for security.
- [Pohlig–Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) (and possibly other algorithms) depending on the factorization of $k$, that do not work as well as Pollard's rho when $k$ is prime.

> Would be a higher value for $g$ increase security?

Not much. The influence of $g$ on security is usually neglected for the aforementioned three algorithm. I doubt it can exceed $\mathcal O(\log g)$ (which can be approached in [Baby-step/Giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step)). Also, I know no way to select a very small $g$ with order $k$ and $\log_2(k)\ll\log_2(P)$, much less for prime $k$, which is desirable for various reasons including blocking Pohlig–Hellman.

> Or to be more certain would a higher smallest group element $\ne 1$ increase security?

Not that we know. Also I know no way to insure that for large parameters.

---

What we are discussing is a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group). There are well established methods to generate these, including from a public seed so as to tame suspicion of weak parameters. See [FIPS 186-4, appendix A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40) (which uses $p,q$ where the question and answer use $P,k$).

---

¹ That function is *at most* about $\alpha k^2$ for a constant $\alpha$ in the order of $2$ depending on a variety of details. But that's immaterial to the reasoning in the paragraph with this note.

² The cost can get down to $O(\log^{1.585\ldots}P)$ with [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) which sometime is used; $O(\log P\;\log\log P\;\log\log\log P)$ with [Schönhage-Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) which could be of interest for insanely large $P$, and $O(\log P\;\log\log P)$ with [Harvey-Hoeven](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/) (a bleeding edge result which seems unlikely to have practical application).

Comment: oh, dear forgot about the increasing $g$ if $P$ gets increased (with const $k$). Excellent answer. Ye, my questions was related to Schnorr group.

Comment: about the lower boundary: It was meant to be a boundary for the ratio $P/k$ (or log ratio). With $P$ 4096 bits the order $k$ could still be a low prime if the other factor is high. E.g. order $k=7$ would be easy to solve, no matter how big $P$ is. As you written above the ratio is not that important. So the order $k$ should be a prime near $2^{4095}$?

Comment: An upper bound of the security would be given by the generic group model: For a given order of a cyclic group, no encoding can be more difficult than ignoring the encoding and just looking at the group structure.

Comment: @J.Doe: I have not introduced the ratio $P/k$ or $\log(P)/\log(k)$; you just did. The relation between reasonable $P$ and $k$ is one difficult to establish. The right ballpark around the values that I state might be that when we multiply the bit size of $k$ by $x$ with $1<x\le2$, we multiply the bit size of $P$ by $x^2$ to $x^3$. I stated that $k$ should be a prime of 256 to 512 bit (given as $2^8$ to $2^9$). Even with a large $P$ (say, 8192-bit) and $k$ prime, if $k<2^{128}$, then it is conceivable to compute the discrete logarithm with distributed Pollard's rho.

Comment: @fgrieu: I meant my initial question was about the ratio. E.g. Let $k$ be fixed size of 512-bit. Does the security decrease if $P=2ck+1$ gets bigger? For $c=1$ the prime $P$ would have 513-bit. For $c$ a 512-bit prime $P$ would have 1025bit and so on. For a very large $c$ like a $2^{100}$-bit prime $P$ would be a $2^{110}$ bit prime. I thought that would involve many multiplications without mod. But as you wrote with higher $k$ also $g$ gets higher and no known way to find a small group element. It even increases security (a little) because multiplications need a little more computation power.

Comment: [about the additional security of increasing $g$]: "I doubt it can exceed $\mathcal{O}( \log g )$"; actually, it can be easily shown that is cannot be more than a factor of 2.  Given an arbitrary DLog problem $h^x = j$, if we have a preferred $g$ that generates the same subgroup, we can reduce this problem into the two problems $g^y = h$ and $g^z = j$, and derive $x$ from $y$ and $z$.  Hence, if we can solve DLog with a small $g$, we can solve it for any generator (with no more than a factor of 2 increase in work)

Comment: @poncho: I had refrained from writing just that, even though I think it is true, because of a gap in (at least my) reasoning. Indeed _"if we **have** a preferred $g$"_, it can't be better than by a factor of about 2. But that preferred $g$ could still be hard to find. For example, in the context of a Schnorr group, it reasonably could be the smallest generator, and I have no efficient algorithm to identify it.

Comment: @fgrieu I've some doubts here ( I'm doing my reverse, upvoted now asking :) ). $k$ is never mentioned to be a large constant (prime) [The Q was bad in the begining]. If $g$ is always selected with order $k$ than increasing the $c$ cannot change the security if attackers know about the factor.

Comment: @kelalaka: I think that increasing $c$ still does increase security (on average, and marginally), because the cost of goup operations grows at least as $\mathcal O(\log c\,\log\log c)$. Would not bet the house on that, though.

Comment: @fgrieu can't we map the $m$ and $g$ via a homomorphism where the cost will be the same. Why do we have to work on the big group?

Comment: @kelalaka:  the inputs $m$ and $P$ have size that grows as $\log P$, and it seems we need to process at least a fixed fraction of both arguments, thus at least the time grows as $\mathcal O(\log P)$, that is $\mathcal O(\log c)$. I admit my argument (not proof due to "seems") for $\mathcal O(\log c\,\log\log c)$ is weaker. The later is based on the even more unproven assumption that we must perform an at least constant number of group operations.

Comment: The smallest value $g$ which may be possible overall should be $\sqrt[k]{P+1}$. For highest smallest group value there might be also a formula. Because it is a Schnorr group each product of $g$ can be a new generator of this group (except $1$)

Comment: @J.Doe: I would guess that the smallest $g$ is _in the order of_ $P/k$ when that's large (for Schnorr groups of cryptographic interest, many hundred bits). But then I know no way to find that $g$.